# After defining the name of a type classes in Haskell, what does the vertical bar followed by a function mean?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, megaparsec

I was taking a look at the `megaparsec` library and noticed that a class is defined as

```
class (Stream s, A.Alternative m, MonadPlus m)
=> MonadParsec e s m | m -> e s where
```

I know that I am creating a type class named MonadParsec, but what does `| m -> e s` mean exactly?

Comment: In a nutshell: it means "`m` uniquely determines both `e` and `s`" (i.e., in this specific example, the parsing monad determines what the error type and the token stream type are).